# Linear transformation calculation don't understand.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am new to linear algebra, today I came across a solution sample as follow:
The sample solution deduces $T(1) = x+3,\ T(x) = 3x+4$ from a transformation: $T(ax+b) = (3a+b)x+a+3$.
I cannot understand this, can somebody please explain this to me? Thanks.

Comment: Let $a=0,b=1$ to get $T(1)$, and $a=1,b=0$ to get $T(x)$.

Comment: If $a=b=0$ then $ax+b=0$ but $T(0)=T(ax+b)=3\neq 0$. Is it correct?

Comment: $T$ is not a linear transformation in the sense of linear algebra -- such functions like this one are usually called "affine" -- unless the dimension is $1$ (as in this example), in which case they are confusingly called "linear" in analytic geometry(i.e. equation of a line, first degree polynomial)

Comment: @ned: you are right. The same effect is obtained with the linear transformation $ax+b\to(3a+b)x+(4a+3b)$, which makes me suspect a flaw in the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

When $a=0$ and $b=1$ we have $T(0x+1)=T(1)=x+3.$

For $a=1$ and $b=0$ we have $T(1x+0)=T(x)=3x+4$ by substituting into the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation is defined by specifying how a first degree binomial is transformed,

$$f(ax+b)=\cdots$$

Now it suffces to make the connections between

$$ax+b\leftrightarrow 1$$

and

$$ax+b\leftrightarrow x,$$ then apply the definition.